# Seeking textbook about ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, references

I am looking for a textbook for ArcGIS Online that is similar to the common textbook, "Getting to know ArcGIS for Desktop".

A text book that simplifies and organizes all the information for Online and provides lessons to practice working with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any textbook about ArcGIS online but here is the one close to it.
https://learn.arcgis.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

It is worth knowing that the release cycle of ArcGIS Online is more frequent than the standard ArcGIS product lifecycle (e.g. 10.3, 10.4).  Therefore with the time it takes to publish a book it might already be somewhat out of date.

With that said, I saw that the Esri press have just released a 2nd edition of ['Getting to Know WebGIS'](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=283). I read the first one can vouch that it is a worthwhile read.

> Getting to Know Web GIS is a workbook with detailed, step-by-step
>   exercises that teaches readers how to share resources online and build
>   web GIS applications easily and quickly. It covers the Esri suite of
>   web GIS technologies, including ArcGIS Online, Portal for ArcGIS,
>   ArcGIS for Server, web app templates, Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS,
>   ArcGIS API for JavaScript, the Collector for ArcGIS mobile app, mobile
>   SDKs, and 3D web scenes.

If you are looking for self-development, I would recommend scouring over the appropriate [videos from Esri](http://video.esri.com/), [The ArcGIS Book,](http://learn.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-book/) and [the Training Site](https://www.esri.com/training/).